# Parsing JSON log files using MS Message Analyzer

Tags: json, microsoft-message-analyzer

A documentation of MS Message Analyzer describes [it can read JSON files](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/jj649797.aspx).

I have a log file with JSON-encoded per line, like this:

```
{"userid":1,"action":"login","timestamp":1463734780036}
{"userid":1,"action":"logout","timestamp":1463734780036}
{"userid":2,"action":"login","timestamp":1463734780036}
{"userid":2,"action":"logout","timestamp":1463734780036}
```

However, it reads only first line.

[image: sample]

I've tried wrapping log entries with an array:

```
[{"userid":1,"action":"login","timestamp":1463734780036},
{"userid":1,"action":"logout","timestamp":1463734780036},
{"userid":2,"action":"login","timestamp":1463734780036},
{"userid":2,"action":"logout","timestamp":1463734780036}]
```

MSMA read this as one big log entry.

[image: sample2]

I want to read each log entry as Message in MSMA, like CSV file:

[image: sample3]

MSMA doesn't support splitting Messages for JSON files?